# QuaggaJS Barcode scanner not working for Android devices

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, barcode-scanner, quaggajs

I have created a barcode scanner in my react component using QuaggaJS.  The scanner is meant to be used on mobile devices through the web view.  It's working fine on all iPhone devices but is not scanning correctly on androids.  I am guessing this is a resolution issue in the constraints but have not found a solution that works.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import Quagga from "@ericblade/quagga2";
import adapter from "webrtc-adapter";
import LogService from "../../services/LogService";
import "./BarcodeScanner.css";

const BarcodeScanner = (props) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const logService = new LogService();
  let mainCameraDeviceId = "";

  

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getBackDevices() {
      await Quagga.CameraAccess.request();

      let devices = await Quagga.CameraAccess.enumerateVideoDevices()
      .then((devices) => devices)
      .catch((err) => {
        logService.Log("Error", "Error when enumerating video devices", err);
        console.error(`${err.name}: ${err.message}`);
      });

      let backDevices = [];

      devices.forEach((device) => {
        logService.Log("Debug", "Detected Device",device);
        if(device.kind.toLowerCase().includes("videoinput") && device.label.toLowerCase().includes("back")) {
          backDevices.push(device);
          console.log(`${device.kind}: ${device.label} id = ${device.deviceId}`);
        }
      });

      if (backDevices.length == 0 && devices.length == 1) {
        backDevices.push(devices[0]);
      }

      logService.Log("Debug", "Detected back devices", backDevices);
      mainCameraDeviceId = backDevices[backDevices.length-1].deviceId;  
      startQuagga();
    }
    
    getBackDevices();
  }, []);


  function startQuagga() {
    logService.Log("Debug", "Selected camera device", mainCameraDeviceId);

    let customConstraints = {
      focusMode: 'continuous',
      facingMode: "environment",
      zoom: {min: 1.5, max: 2},
      deviceId: mainCameraDeviceId,
      width: 640,
      height: 480
    }
    
    if(props.deviceType == "iPhone") {
      customConstraints.width = { min: 480 };
      customConstraints.height = { min: 1281 };
    }

    

    logService.Log("Debug", "Device Type", props.deviceType);
    logService.Log("Debug", "Quagga constraints", customConstraints);

    try {
      Quagga.init(
        {
          inputStream: {
            name: "Live",
            type: "LiveStream",
            target: document.querySelector("#interactive"),
            constraints: customConstraints
          },
          locate: true,
          decoder: {
            readers: [
              "upc_reader"
            ],
            multiple: false
          },
        },
        function (err) {
          if (err != null) {
            console.log(err);
            props.onError(err);
            stopScanner();
            return;
          }
          console.log("Initialization finished. Ready to start");
          Quagga.start();
        }
      );
    } catch {
      props.onError("Failed to open camera");
    }
  }

  Quagga.onDetected((data) => {
    props.onDetected(data.codeResult.code);
    Quagga.stop();

  });


  const stopScanner = () => {
    console.log("stopping Quagga");
    Quagga.stop();
  };


  return (
    <div
    
      className="barcode-scanner viewport"
      id="interactive"
    >
      
      <div className="box-overlay"></div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default BarcodeScanner;
```

Comment: I don't know if this will help (only just started looking at Quagga myself) but I spotted that there's the following library which seems to have added some features to QuaggaJS https://github.com/ericblade/quagga2